# Mudar status de acordo com a data

Tags: php, javascript, html

Estou com uma tremenda dúvida de como eu poderia resolver/criar a solução.
Eu poderia fazer manualmente criando um select do lado e mudando o status da corrida após submit, mas a ideia é a seguinte:
Como eu posso criar uma condição, seja ela no back-end/php  que ao chegar a data mencionada mudar/preencher o STATUS para "CORRIDA EFETUADA".

Meu banco existem os 2 campos abaixo:

> No BD:
> date type: varchar;
> status: varchar;

Campos html:

```
<div class="form-group col-md-3">
    <label><b>1° - Data e Hora</b></label>
    <input type="datetime-local" name="dt_corrida1" id="data_corrida" 
        class="form-control" value="<?php echo $row[0]['dt_corrida1']; ?>"  
        placeholder="Data Corrida">
</div>
<div class="form-group col-md-3">
    <label><b>STATUS</b></label>
    <input type="text" name="status" id="status" class="form-control" 
        value="<?php echo $row[0]['status']; ?>">
</div>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

EDIT:
Imagem de como está no banco de dados. O Type não está como datetime porque eu não consegui trazer a informação no input com a type "datetime-local", somente com varchar.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Informação registrada no BD:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

INPUTS:

**DATA CORRIDA VINDO DO BD puxando a partir da row.**

```
<input type="datetime-local" name="dt_corrida1" id="data_corrida" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $row[0]['dt_corrida1']; ?>"  placeholder="Data Corrida">
```

**STATUS:**

```
<input readonly type="text" name="status" id="status" class="form-control" value="">
```

EDIT IMAGEM DOS INPUTS E STATUS - troquei os ids que foi solicitado e o js substitui conforme editado.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Obrigado desde já!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dai você adiciona para não perder o input do `data_corrida`, creio que vc já fez isso no `$row[0]['dt_corrida1'];`, mas enfim faz uma `function` que ao carregar ela é executada. O modelo em que fica o input type datetime-local é **ANO-MÊS-DIATHORA:MINUTOS**, dai pega o ano atual, o mês atual, o dia atual, a hora atual e os minutos atuais, e transforma em tudo em uma string do mesmo modelo que fica no input, compara e quando eles forem iguais aparece o "CORRIDA EFETUADA". A e adicionei a tag `readonly` no input do status, para quem estiver acessando não conseguir digitar nele.

**Edição:**
Utilize o `slice()` para "recortar" a string e pegar o ano, mes, dia... e faz que quando a data atual seja maior apareça o "CORRIDA EFETUADA", e se ainda a data não chegou o status fica vazio.

```js
function compararData(){
var data = new Date();
var month = data.getUTCMonth() + 1;
var day = data.getUTCDate();
var year = data.getUTCFullYear();
var hour = data.getHours();
var min = data.getMinutes();
if (min < 10) {
   min = "0" + min
}
if (day < 10){
    day = "0" + day
}
if (month < 10){
    month = "0" + month
}

agora = year + "-" + month + "-" + day + "T" + hour + ":" + min

for (let i =1; i<=15; i++){
dataCorrida = document.getElementById('data_corrida'+i)
StatusCorrida =  document.getElementById('status'+i)
  
    if (dataCorrida.value.length >= 16) {
    if (dataCorrida.value == agora){
        StatusCorrida.value = "CORRIDA EFETUADA"
    }
    if (year > dataCorrida.value.slice(0,4)){
            StatusCorrida.value = "CORRIDA EFETUADA"
    }
    if (dataCorrida.value.slice(0,4) == year && month > dataCorrida.value.slice(5,7)){
            StatusCorrida.value = "CORRIDA EFETUADA"
    }
    if (dataCorrida.value.slice(0,4) == year && dataCorrida.value.slice(5,7) == month && day > dataCorrida.value.slice(8,10)){
            StatusCorrida.value = "CORRIDA EFETUADA"
    }
    if (dataCorrida.value.slice(0,4) == year && dataCorrida.value.slice(5,7) == month && dataCorrida.value.slice(8,10) == day && hour > dataCorrida.value.slice(11,13)) {
           StatusCorrida.value = "CORRIDA EFETUADA"
    }
    if (dataCorrida.value.slice(0,4) == year && dataCorrida.value.slice(5,7) == month && dataCorrida.value.slice(8,10) == day && dataCorrida.value.slice(11,13) == hour && min > dataCorrida.value.slice(14,16)) {
           StatusCorrida.value = "CORRIDA EFETUADA"
    }
    }
    }
    setInterval(compararData,500)
}
```

```html
<body onload="compararData()">
    <div class="form-group col-md-3">
        <label><b>1° - Data e Hora</b></label>
        <input type="datetime-local" name="dt_corrida1" id="data_corrida1" class="form-control"  placeholder="Data Corrida">
    </div>
<div class="form-group col-md-3">
        <label><b>STATUS</b></label>
        <input readonly type="text" name="status" id="status" class="form-control" value="">
    </div>
    
</body>
```

***OBS: Retirei os trechos em PHP só para vc testar ai no Stack***

espero ter ajudado

Comment: Por favor evitem longas discussões nos comentários; a conversa de vocês foi [movida para o chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118037/discussion-on-answer-by-noface-mudar-status-de-acordo-com-a-data)